# Accessing session attributes set in a HttpServlet in a WebSocketServlet (Jetty WebSockets)

Tags: java, kotlin, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to access session attributes set in a `HttpServlet` from a `WebSocketServlet`

I have two `ServletContextHandler` objects, both with `SESSIONS` enabled:

```kotlin
val httpHandler = object : ServletContextHandler(nullParent, contextPath, SESSIONS).apply {
    addServlet(ServletHolder(httpServlet), "/*")
}

val webSocketHandler = ServletContextHandler(nullParent, contextPath, SESSIONS).apply {
    addServlet(ServletHolder(wsServlet), "/*")
}
```

These are attached as a `HandlerList(httpHandler, webSocketHandler)` to my Jetty `Server`. The first line of the `doHandle` of the `ServletContextHandler` for the `HttpHandler` checks if the request is a WebSocket upgrade request, and returns immediately if it is (in which case it's handed over to the `ServletContextHandler` for the `WebSocketServlet`).

I have a simple `POST` endpoint which sets a session attribute, but I'm unable to retrieve this session attribute in the `WebSocketServlet`:

```kotlin
class MyWsServlet : WebSocketServlet() {

    override fun configure(factory: WebSocketServletFactory) {
        factory.creator = WebSocketCreator { req, res ->
            // session exists here, but req.session.getAttribute("any-attr") is always null
        }
    }

    override fun service(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse) {
        // session also exists here, but req.session.getAttribute("any-attr") is always null
    }

}
```

Any advice or suggestions welcome.

Edit: I've included some debug information from a GET request vs a WebSocket request after `req.session.setAttribute("test", "tast")` has been called:

```
Path: /
Cookies:{JSESSIONID=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0.node0}
Session: Session@24b04e4{id=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0,x=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0.node0,req=1,res=true}
Session id: node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0
Session isNew: false
Session attributes: {test=tast}
---------------------------
Path: /websocket
Cookies:{JSESSIONID=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0.node0}
Session: Session@5989f3d1{id=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0,x=node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0.node0,req=1,res=true}
Session id: node01cxyhb0addjwikyb2lgtnlxlw0
Session isNew: false
Session attributes: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of your 2 `ServletContextHandler`, use one.   You cannot have two handlers on the same contextPath anyway.

Also, you have 2 major ways you can implement Jetty Server WebSockets, using the `WebSocketServlet`, or using a `WebSocketUpgradeFilter`.   The biggest difference is that using the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` you can have multiple mappings pointing to any number of WebSocket endpoints, using Servlet url-pattern notation, or URI-template notation, or even regex notation.

If the problem persists after you do that, then it sounds like your client is either not sending the `Cookie` header that Jetty needs, or sending the wrong one (eg: a `Cookie` header pointing to a different / new `HttpSession` reference).

Capture the traffic between your client and server, pay attention to the client `Cookie` value, as well as any `Set-Cookie` values seen in responses from the server.

You can alternatively have a filter that just dumps the active `HttpSession` details on every request.  Make sure it shows the `HttpSession.getId()`, the `HttpSession.isNew()` and dumps all of the attributes (via combination of `.getAttributeNames()` and `getAttribute(String name)` calls).

Comment: > First, get rid of your 2 ServletContextHandler, use one. You cannot have two handlers on the same contextPath anyway --- I cannot add them to the same ServletContextHandler ("Multiple servlets map to path /*:"). How can I solve this if I want to have the same root path? I will update my question to include cookies and session ids.

Comment: Use the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` instead of extending from `WebSocketServlet` then.

Comment: Thanks, after rewriting to WebSocketUpgradeFilter I managed to get the session attribute !